# How can I add tag value in sender while creating an UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I'm very noob with swift, so i Have a question for solve a trouble in my app.

In a UIView i have just added a Collection View as a Sub View, then in each cell I added a different IMAGE inside a "Wrapper View", so my question is...

How can i add a gesture that receives the tag value by a sender for each cell? For example, when i tap the cell it'll print the indexPath

I have this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{


    var cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell;

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0);

    //Agregamos imagen a la celda
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width - 0, cell.frame.height - 0))
    var image = UIImage(named: "car_aguas_gerber_7.png")
    imageView.image = image
    cell.backgroundView = UIView()
    cell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageView)



    // Sección donde creamos el TAP para cada imageView

    // Creamos el tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGesture:")

    // Se lo adjudicamos al image view previo
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    // Nos aseguramos que tenga interacción hacia el usuario
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true


    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    println(cell.tag);


    //Una vez creada la celda la regresamos completa.
    return cell;


}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your knowledge and help :)

Comment: By means of UICollectionView delegate method `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and in this method call  `[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];` It returns the tapped cell. To get its tag, just get it's tag property

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm very new to this language...is it swift??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just have it when adding the gesture recognizer to the cell. When the gesture happens, the parameter passed will be the cell. So when declaring the tapGesture method you just access the sender's tag property.

```
func tapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var tag = sender.view!.tag
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I've already used it but when i tap the cell, it marks the following error:


2015-06-19 09:39:47.322 iNesbook[2608:37458] -[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b38f3f580
2015-06-19 09:39:47.435 iNesbook[2608:37458] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b38f3f580'
*** First throw call stack:
(
...
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException


Is anything wrong with my declaration?

Comment: sorry, the sender is of type UITapGestureRecognizer, so you have to access the view attached to it and get its tag, I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks!! it works like a charm!!!!! but just for collective knowledge the correct syntax in swift is the following statement:  

    func tapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        println(sender.view!.tag);
    }

Just add the '!' symbol ;)