# Custom property collectionviewcell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I use this code to show a collection of images, which are scrollable. However, I would like to add a property to make it possible to identify each cell or image in this case. I want a property to every cell that can hold a string.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PalletsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PalletsCollectionViewCell

    cell.imgImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Haven't found anything while reading the swift documentation.

What I want to do is to add events to the cells. If the user touches a cell, a function will be called. This function performs an API request with the property value as parameter.

Comment: Have you tried `didSelectCellAtIndex`? Or, if you want something specific to be tappable you could attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the View you want tappable.

Comment: @Michael I don't want the index of the cell I want to assign each cell a value and get that value when a cell has been tapped. This value can be something like an ID for explanation purpose.

Comment: Use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and set a `tag` on the `sender`. Like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30927758/2415921

Comment: The value shouldn't be set on TapGesture but on initialise of the cells.

Comment: You set the `tag` of the `view` in `cellForRowAtIndex`, apply a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `view`, and reference the `tag` as the `sender.tag` on the tap.

Or you can encapsulate the logic inside of the cell itself and pass the value you need to the cell. (I'd probably lean more towards that)

Comment: @Michael Hi, could we chat? I've become further however I only see a black bar instead of the content. I've checked my delegates.

Comment: Hey @LifeOS, post your code in the question and I'll take a look.